# can i apply tailwind css in multiple html files that are placed in the same folder?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-elements

I am learning tailwind and i am new in it. When I try to create multiple html files in a folder and try to apply tailwind, it is applying the property only to the first html file i have created. And moreover, when i am trying to open other html files , still the first html file is opening, maybe I am asking a silly question , but an answer regarding that will be truly appreciated..

I have first created an index.html file and apply tailwind in it. It works.
But then i created another file named as "index1.html" and when i linked the file to my tailwind-css, again the first one "index.html" is opening. So i just want to ask can we apply tailwind to multiple html files  in same folder , if yes how?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can place multiple html files in the same folder and the tailwind applies to them as well, if u have installed and configured it correctly. As far as the accessibility concern is required, by default you browser URL will be showing something like `http://localhost:5173`, for example, It by default moves to index.html, If you desire to check your `index1.html`, just go on the address bar and write the name of your html file next to local host e.g. `http://localhost:5173/index1.html`.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply tailwind to multiple html files.
To do that, you have to update your `tailwind.config.js` file.

As per [tailwind's documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration), you could configure the path to all your HTML files' path.

So your solution would be:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './index.html',
    './index1.html',
  ],
  // ...
}
```